# XML Transformation to HTML using XSLT not validating because of attribute "required"

Tags: html, validation, xslt, input, marshalling

I've got a big xml-file which is transformed to
be shown as html in the browser.
This html view includes a formular.
The problem occurs, when the marshalling happens by the servlet.
It shows, that the file **is not well formed because of the attribute "required"**,
which is used for the input fields.

Here the specific line of my **xsl-file**:

```
<input class="input" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" required/>
```

I already had to add the "/>" instead of just ">" at the end of "input".
I was also able to fix this problem using the following instead:

```
<input class="input" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" required="yes"/>
```

This works but doesn't seem to be a good solution because it doesn't
change anything if I just write required="yes" or ="no" or ="true" or ="false"...

It would be great if you guys know a better solution for this problem.
**Thanks!**

Comment: what you did is the solution. a valueless attribute is valid html but not xml so therefore your xsl wont parse. since html doesn't care what the value of required attribute is just give it whatever.

Comment: Yes, I already noticed this and made it required="" at the end. I just asked this question because it seems a bit pointless to say required="" or it doesnt matter what and wondered if there is any better solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `required="required"`. If your output method is `html` and your processor is new enough to be aware of HTML 5, the output will be `required`. Otherwise the output will be `required="required"` (as prescribed by XHTML).

http://xsltransform.net/gVhD8R6